# Use Ajax response as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery

I am using a javascript library caleed JSCharts for generating line, bar graphs and so on. Everything is working like it should, I can provide a working example:

```
var myData = new Array(['2013-01-24', 117], ['2013-01-25', 91], ['2013-01-26', 90], ['2013-01-27', 128], ['2013-01-28', 168], ['2013-01-29', 169], ['2013-01-30', 146], ['2013-01-31', 48], ['2013-02-01', 66], ['2013-02-02', 48], ['2013-02-03', 90], ['2013-02-04', 138], ['2013-02-05', 77], ['2013-02-06', 55], ['2013-02-07', 79], ['2013-02-08', 63], ['2013-02-09', 35], ['2013-02-10', 63], ['2013-02-11', 90], ['2013-02-12', 80], ['2013-02-13', 48], ['2013-02-14', 62], ['2013-02-15', 71], ['2013-02-16', 52], ['2013-02-17', 95], ['2013-02-18', 69], ['2013-02-19', 94], ['2013-02-20', 119], ['2013-02-21', 725], ['2013-02-22', 1348], ['2013-02-23', 1244], ['2013-02-24', 607], ['2013-02-25', 585], ['2013-02-26', 941], ['2013-02-27', 1466], ['2013-02-28', 1015], ['2013-03-01', 1626], ['2013-03-02', 965], ['2013-03-03', 875], ['2013-03-04', 841], ['2013-03-05', 969], ['2013-03-06', 710], ['2013-03-07', 566], ['2013-03-08', 660], ['2013-03-09', 622], ['2013-03-10', 651], ['2013-03-11', 679], ['2013-03-12', 812], ['2013-03-13', 754], ['2013-03-14', 669], ['2013-03-15', 661], ['2013-03-16', 328], ['2013-03-17', 529], ['2013-03-18', 552], ['2013-03-19', 647], ['2013-03-20', 462], ['2013-03-21', 452], ['2013-03-22', 157], ['2013-03-23', 188], ['2013-03-24', 103], ['2013-03-25', 152], ['2013-03-26', 155], ['2013-03-27', 165], ['2013-03-28', 952], ['2013-03-29', 1135], ['2013-03-30', 915], ['2013-03-31', 996], ['2013-04-01', 400], ['2013-04-02', 204], ['2013-04-03', 145], ['2013-04-04', 164], ['2013-04-05', 1248], ['2013-04-06', 517], ['2013-04-07', 300], ['2013-04-08', 494], ['2013-04-09', 248], ['2013-04-10', 220], ['2013-04-11', 245], ['2013-04-12', 152], ['2013-04-13', 109], ['2013-04-14', 293], ['2013-04-15', 207], ['2013-04-16', 120], ['2013-04-17', 528], ['2013-04-18', 266], ['2013-04-19', 286], ['2013-04-20', 313], ['2013-04-21', 162], ['2013-04-22', 310]);
console.log("myData: " + Object.prototype.toString.call(myData));
var myChart = new JSChart('116376655202954_3months_page_views_chartcontainer', 'line');
myChart.setDataArray(myData);
myChart.setSize(960, 320);
myChart.setAxisNameX('');
myChart.setAxisValuesColorX('#FFFFFF');
myChart.setAxisNameY('');
myChart.setTitle('Page Views in the last 3 months');
Chart.draw();
```

My issue is that now I make an Ajax GET request to a php file that sends me as response the following:

```
['2013-02-24', 10], ['2013-02-25', 17], ['2013-02-26', 23], ['2013-02-27', 13], ['2013-02-28', 11], ['2013-03-01', 12], ['2013-03-02', 6], ['2013-03-03', 20], ['2013-03-04', 21], ['2013-03-05', 18], ['2013-03-06', 12], ['2013-03-07', 17], ['2013-03-08', 10], ['2013-03-09', 7], ['2013-03-10', 6], ['2013-03-11', 13], ['2013-03-12', 24], ['2013-03-13', 20], ['2013-03-14', 15], ['2013-03-15', 12], ['2013-03-16', 4], ['2013-03-17', 21], ['2013-03-18', 18], ['2013-03-19', 21], ['2013-03-20', 10], ['2013-03-21', 4], ['2013-03-22', 2], ['2013-03-23', 9], ['2013-03-24', 7], ['2013-03-25', 13], ['2013-03-26', 2], ['2013-03-27', 9], ['2013-03-28', 15], ['2013-03-29', 14], ['2013-03-30', 29], ['2013-03-31', 19], ['2013-04-01', 6], ['2013-04-02', 4], ['2013-04-03', 7], ['2013-04-04', 5], ['2013-04-05', 56], ['2013-04-06', 3], ['2013-04-07', 2], ['2013-04-08', 11], ['2013-04-09', 4], ['2013-04-10', 7], ['2013-04-11', 1], ['2013-04-12', 6], ['2013-04-13', 2], ['2013-04-14', 2], ['2013-04-15', 6], ['2013-04-16', 3], ['2013-04-17', 13], ['2013-04-18', 5], ['2013-04-19', 7], ['2013-04-20', 4], ['2013-04-21', 4], ['2013-04-22', 8]
```

Here is my code for the GET request:

```
function submitForm(t) {
    var page_id = String("#" + $(t).attr('id'));
    $.ajax({type:'GET', url: 'charts.php', data:$(page_id).serialize(), success:
        function(response) {
            document.getElementById('<?php echo $account['id']; ?>_fan_removes').style.display = "block";
            console.log(response);
            var myFanRemovesData = new Array(response);
            console.log(myFanRemovesData);
            var myChart = new JSChart('116376655202954_fan_removes', 'line');
            myChart.setDataArray(myFanRemovesData);
            myChart.setSize(960, 320);
            myChart.setAxisNameX('');
            myChart.setAxisValuesColorX('#FFFFFF');
            myChart.setAxisNameY('');
            myChart.setTitle('Page Fan Removes in the last 2 months');
            myChart.draw();
        }});
    return false;
};
```

I know that the response is a string and I want it to be placed like in the working example but I can't get it to work properly. The `myData` and `myFanRemovesData` are [object Array] but if I use console.log on both I receive the following:
For `myData`:

```
[Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], ... ]
```

which is an array of arrays and for `myFanRemovesData`:

```
["['2013-02-24', 10], ['2013-02-25', 17], ['2013-02-…-04-20', 4], ['2013-04-21', 4], ... "]
```

I've tried to convert the response to array but with no visible success. I don't know what to do next so any suggestions and guidance is more than welcomed.

Comment: Best thing would be to wrap the results in PHP in an array and set the `dataType` for the `ajax` request as `json`

Comment: I'm guessing this isn't a JavaScript issue but more of a PHP issue. Modify your PHP `echo` statement to be the following: `echo json_encode(variable);` where **variable** is the current value you are echoing out.

Comment: `json_encode` sends me each of the array between " like this: `"['2013-02-24', 10]"` how do I build an array of arrays with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php file is returning you a string. You need to convert it to JSON before parsing it in Jquery.

For more info, check this tutorial: http://www.islandsmooth.com/2010/04/send-and-receive-json-data-using-ajax-jquery-and-php/

Comment: indeed, if you use $.post it wil detect automaticaly that its jquery and converts it to an object